# Combine two predicates of different type

Tags: c#, expression, predicate, linq-expressions, predicatebuilder

I have built a predicate by the Address model (`Expression<Func<Address, bool>> addressPred`). Now i want to combine this with a predicate of the Person model (`Expression<Func<Person, bool>> personPred`). Example of the  models are:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
}
```

If I do something like

```
addressPred = addressPred.And(a => a.StreetName == "Foo bar");
```

and then combine it with the personPred, the combined predicate will have a statement equalent to

```
combinedPred = combinedPred.And(a => a.Address.StreetName == "Foo bar");
```

The combinedPredicate is of type `Person`.
How can I achive this?

**Edit:**
In reality the models are alot bigger and are shortened for simplicity's sake. What I ultimately want to achive is to build the Address predicate once, then build a predicate for Person with its own conditions and then combine it into a predicate where the Address-part of the Person predicate comes from the Address predicate (Address is a property of Person). The reason I want to do it this way is because Address may have alot of conditions, and I want to use it as a part of other predicates (Person, later also Company, Customer etc) before making a db-call (to Person, Company, Customer etc)
Also the `combinedPred` line of code was only to show what the equalent statement of the `combinedPred` would be like coming from Address predicate.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're asking. Where does the `personPred` fit into all of this? The `combinedPred` doesn't appear to use it, and has its own logic for getting an `Address` object. Please improve your question so it makes sense.

Comment: You would need to wrap up your address-related predicate in a person-related one, such as `p => addressPred(p.Address)`. Also, make sure you post the actual *types* of things, as well as an example of what you want to accomplish. Right now there's a lot of unknown types and handwaving so it's a bit unclear **exactly** what you're asking.

Comment: Note: the suggestion above by @Lasse is syntactically correct, but does not make use of any `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>`, i.e. a `Person` predicate. A predicate, by definition, returns a `bool` value. There is nothing in your question that explains what you mean by "combine" such that the final predicate only has a single Boolean expression and doesn't use any predicate that takes a `Person` at all.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope it is now more clear what I am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation is that the built `Expression<Func<Address, bool>> addressPred` has an address as `ParameterExpression` and it is requred to apply the expression to a `MemberExpression`. So I can suggest to replace the `ParameterExpression` with the `MemberExpression` like that:

```
var personParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "person");
var addressProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(personParameter, "Address");        
var combined = new ReplaceVisitor<Address>(addressProperty).Visit(addressPred.Body);
var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(combined, personParameter);
```

Where:

```
public class ReplaceVisitor<T> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly MemberExpression _replacement;

    public ReplaceVisitor(MemberExpression replacement)
    {
        _replacement = replacement;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node.Type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
                ? _replacement : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! :)